# Attaching a defect to a blocked Test Case in QC

Tags: quality-center

In QC there is an option to set a "Blocked" status for a testing scenarios which are unable to be tested due to a blocking defect. I wonder if there is an option to attach the actual blocking defect to these tests?

Of course it is possible to just include it "Comments" field but maybe there is a more neat way to do it?

Comment: I used to work with QC and there is a way, but I no longer use it so can't provide any detailed instructions

Comment: Can you please tell how you are blocking the scenario? Then may be I can help.

Comment: @asma Yes, this is just one of the available test case statuses. The others are: Passed, Failed, Not Completed ...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this [video](http://www.guru99.com/quality-center-tutorial-10.html) will be useful to answer this question. But it is a very common question which you would have found just by Googling :/

Comment: Two things to note -
1) QC version may be different
2) Blocked TC is not a special case I believe :)